# Can an automorphism of a group which stabilizes a subgroup fail to restrict to an automorphism of the subgroup?

Tags: group-theory

Does there exist a group $G$, a subgroup $N\le G$, and an automorphism $\alpha$ of $G$ such that $\alpha(N)\subset N$, but $\alpha$ does not restrict to an automorphism of $N$?

Equivalently, can there be subgroups of a group which are stable under an automorphism of the ambient group, but not stable under its inverse?

Comment: Yes, when the group is infinite this can even happen for conjugation (there is a nice duplicate target with this case, but I can't find it right now).

Comment: $G=\Bbb Q$, $N=\Bbb Z$, $\alpha(x)=2x$

Comment: @user8268 Ah, great. If you post your comment as an answer I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: It restricts ton an injective endomorphism of $N$. Conversely, every injective endomorphism $f$ of a group $N$ extends to an automorphism of some larger group, namely the inductive limit of $N\stackrel{f}\to N\stackrel{f}\to N\dots$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G=\Bbb Q$, $N=\Bbb Z$, $\alpha(x)=2x$